# Python regex: 'exceptions.IndexError: string index out of range'

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I am using a simple regex to replace instances of strings in the format 'id="111111". These strings are derived as part of a webpage response generated using scrapy and filtered using another regex to give me only the output I want. I'm using re.sub in the following fashion:

```
match3 = re.sub("/id="[0-9]+"/", ' ', match3)
```

However, this is throwing up the following error:

```
exceptions.IndexError: string index out of range
```

Can anyone explain to me what the issue is here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No delimiters are needed for a pattern in python.
2. You're closing the pattern (which is a string) when you use `"[0-9...`

The correct method would be:

```
match3 = re.sub( 'id="\d+"', ' ', match3 )   # using a different enclosure
```

or

```
match3 = re.sub( "id=\"[0-9]+\"", ' ', match3 )  # escaping the "
```